# Resolving exports is not defined error

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, amd, tsconfig

I am building a webpage using [html](/questions/tagged/html) and [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript).  The way it is set up is that the html page includes a [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) script which is the transpiled version of the Typescript file.  I'm doing this to take advantage of the `import` statement in Typescript as well as the strong typing.  The problem I'm running into is that I can't seem to transpile the Typescript correctly.  I have tried using [amd](/questions/tagged/amd), [commonjs](/questions/tagged/commonjs), [es2015](/questions/tagged/es2015), and [umd](/questions/tagged/umd) as the module options, but I have run into various errors with each of these methods.  I know I am missing something here as far as how to correctly transpile to Javascript, but I'm not sure what it is that I'm missing. Which module can I use to transpile the Typescript code so I can include it in the html page?

### Errors

- exports is not defined (commonjs)
- define is not defined (amd)
- unexpected token import (es2015)

### html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/WebResources/ccseq_/Content/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/ProductEvaluation.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="product-eval-areas" >
        <div v-if="allowReviewerReview" class="list-group">
            <div class="list-group-item" v-for="area in areas">
                {{area.EvaluationArea}}<star-rating v-model="area.ProductEvaluationScore" v-bind:increment="1" v-bind:star-size="20"></star-rating>
            </div>
        </div>        

        <button v-if="allowReviewerReview" class="btn btn-sm" v-on:click="submitEval">Submit Evaluation</button>

        <p v-if="alert">{{alertMessage}}</p>
    </div>    

    <script src="/WebResources/ccseq_/Scripts/jquery3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="/WebResources/ccseq_bootstrap"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/papaparse.js"></script>
    <script src="../../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/ProductEvaluationReview.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

### typescript

*I excluded some functions for brevity*

```
"use strict";

import { Constants } from "../../CCSEQ/Constants";
import { WebAPI } from "../../CCSEQ/WebAPI";
import { Xrm } from "../../CCSEQ/Xrm";
import * as Model from "../../CCSEQ/Model";
import { Helpers } from "../../CCSEQ/Helpers";
import * as Vue from "vue";
import * as StarRating from "vue-star-rating";

let currentProductEvaluation = new Model.ProductEvaluation();

Vue.component('star-rating', StarRating.default);

let prodEvalAreas = new Vue({
    el: '#product-eval-areas',
    data: {
        //data
    },
    computed: {
        // Computed stuff
    },
    methods: {
        // Methods
    }
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    PopulatePage();
});

function PopulatePage() {
    //Do stuff to populate page

}
}
```

### tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es5",
      "es2015.promise"
    ],
    "module": "umd",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot",
    "./WebResources/js/lib",
    "./WebResources/js/main"
  ],
  "include": [
    "./CCSEQ",
    "./WebResources/js"
  ]
}
```

Comment: For AMD, you need to use a dedicated loader. CommonJS is used on the server. UMD did not get you any errors?

Comment: @Bergi UMD didn't throw an error, but also didn't appear to work correctly

Comment: @Tim Hutchison did you find any solution to this?